# How to pass value to another component in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I try to use event with type="APPLICATION" in my superbadge step, but can't to get the result even from the simple second component.

I need to get my boat's Id when I press "Search" button. In both alerts I get it. But not in the second component. What is wrong here?

**FormSubmit.evt:**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <aura:attribute name="eventAttribute" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

**BoatSearchForm.cmp:**

```
<aura:component controller="BoatSearchFormApex" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:registerEvent name="formSubmit" type="c.FormSubmit"/>

<aura:attribute name="types" type='String[]' default='All'/>
<aura:attribute name="showNewButton" type="Boolean" default="true"/>

<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="end" class="layoutClass">
    <lightning:select aura:id="types" name="types" variant="label-hidden" label="">
        <option value="allTypesValue">All Types</option>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.types}" var="type">
            <option value="{!type.Id}">{!type.Name}</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Search" onclick="{!c.onFormSubmit}"/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showNewButton}">
        <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="New" onclick="{!c.newBoat}"/>
    </aura:if>
</lightning:layout>
```

**Function in controller:**

```
({    
onFormSubmit : function(component, event, helper){
    var typeId = component.find("types").get("v.value");
    alert(typeId);
    var formSubmit = $A.get("e.c:FormSubmit");
    formSubmit.setParams({"eventAttribute" : typeId})
    var test = formSubmit.getParam("eventAttribute");
    alert(test);
    formSubmit.fire();
},
})
```

**cmp2 for test:**

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="Get" type="String"/>
<aura:handler event="c:FormSubmit" action="act"/>
The result is {!v.Get}  
</aura:component>
```

**cmp2Controller.js:**

```
({
act : function(component, event, helper) {
    var show = event.getParam("eventAttribute");
    component.set("v.Get", show);
}
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Your aura:handler tag has `action="act"`, when it should be `action="{!c.act}"`. Don't forget that it has to point to a controller action.

Also, on your declaration, you're using a period instead of a semicolon. Change this
`<aura:registerEvent name="formSubmit" type="c.FormSubmit"/>`
to this
`<aura:registerEvent name="formSubmit" type="c:FormSubmit"/>`

Comment: You're welcome. If this ends up helping, mark the answer as accepted so others can benefit. :)

Comment: @user60684 If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.